# SQL Server : insert record if not duplicate over certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have very limited experience with SQL, so I am struggling to ask the right question.

Imagine I have a table with 5 columns

```
Simulation_ID   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3   Param_4  Param_5  Output_folder
```

This table summarizes simulations that are run using certain parameters, and the output folder of the result.

I would like to prevent duplicates from being inserted in this table. In my case, a simulation must have a unique set of parameters. Therefore, no simulation should have the same combination of parameters. I was tempted to define a primary key as `(ID, Param_1, Param_2, Param_3, Param_4, Param_5)`, but I read that composite keys are not recommended due to poor performance. Currently, `Simulation_ID` is the primary key of the table.

Imagine if someone wants to add a simulation that has a unique ID, but the same set of parameters that was used by another existing record.

Example:

Current data in the table:

```
Simulation_ID   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3   Param_4  Param_5  Output_folder
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1               0.5       0.4       0.3       0.2      0.1      folder1
2               10        0.4       0.3       0.2      0.1      folder2
```

And the new record is:

```
Simulation_ID   Param_1   Param_2   Param_3   Param_4  Param_5  Output_folder
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
3               0.5       0.4       0.3       0.2      0.1      folder3
```

Technically, this record, although having a different ID and `output_folder`, has the exact same values (`Param_1` to `Param_5`) as record #1. I would like to do a check where if this happens, an error is thrown and the record isn't inserted.

Is that possible? In reality, my table has over 20 columns, and 17 out of 20 columns is what I would like to use to flag and prevent duplicates.

Comment: [Create Unique Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-unique-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: [Constraints](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/unique-constraints-and-check-constraints?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: @Jdub Yes correct, however as I mentioned in the post, it is my understanding that composite primary keys (in my case, over 18 columns), is highly discouraged.

Comment: A Primary Key and a Unique Constraint are not the same thing, @Mayou .

Comment: @Larnu Thanks! I figured as much. 'Jdub' originally mentioned a primary key constraint. However, I am still not 100% sure I understand the different between primary key vs. unique constraint. I will read up more on that. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I haven't asked a question on StackOverflow in a while, and I am a bit confused why the question was downvoted.. Was the question in violation of some rule?

Comment: The tooltip for the downvote button is "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful", @Mayou . When someone downvotes this *normally* means that the person agrees with at least one of those points.

Comment: Other possible reasons for a DV (and noting that you are an experienced site user): _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened._

Comment: Thanks for the constructive comments! I haven't used the site in a while so I am a little rusty!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a unique constraint or (equivalently) a unique index.  You would add this as:

```
alter table t add constraint unq_t_params
    unique (param_1, param_2, param_3, param_4, param_5);
```

If you attempt to add a set of parameters that are already in the table, this will return an error, preventing the insertion from happening.

Comment: Thank you so much for this! May I ask how different a unique constraint is from a primary key constraint? Was I right in my understanding of composite primary keys being discouraged? If so, is that not an issue with UNIQUE constraints? Thanks

Comment: You can have only one primary key. Rows on disk will be ordered by the primary key. You cannot have nulls in primary key. As for unique constraints, it only tells SQL that the data needs to be unique. You can have multiple unique constraints on a table. You can have null columns in unique constraints. Data will not be ordered by the unique constraint. I think that sums it up but you should go read more on it.

Comment: @DaniellePaquette-Harvey: *Rows on disk will be ordered by the primary key* - actually - ***NO*** they are ordered by the **clustering index** - not the primary key column(s). Yes, granted - in most cases, this is the same thing - but not always! Please be precise when making such claims!

Comment: @Mayou . . . You can have a five-part primary key.  I don't really recommend it -- it makes foreign key references a real pain.  A primary key has two characteristics beyond uniqueness -- no `NULL` values and only one primary key per table.

Comment: Yes sorry @marc_s you are right, I should have been more precise. It was clear in my head but I didn't specify it.

Comment: May I follow up on this question and ask how can I later retrieve the rows that are duplicates of the new entries that the user is trying to insert?

Comment: @Mayou . . . You would do that with a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: I thought maybe there is a neater way of doing it than trying to match the values over 20 columns. I guess there isn't. Thanks!